# Cannot close stream until all bytes are written (GoodData API)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gooddata

I've done a bit of searching, and most people seem to hit this when sending larger amounts of data, but I'm not.

I'm making a request to an API with the following:

```
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "$Version=0; GDCAuthTT=" + TToken + "; $Path=/gdc/account");

//generate request parameters
ReportRequest.RootObject reportRequest = new ReportRequest.RootObject();
reportRequest.report_req = new ReportRequest.ReportReq();
reportRequest.report_req.reportDefinition = ReportLink;
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializer.Serialize(reportRequest));
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8, byteArray.Length))
{
    writer.Write(byteArray);
}
```

The exception occurs on the last closing bracket:

> Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: Cannot close stream until
>   all bytes are written.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 176:            { Line 177:
>   writer.Write(byteArray); Line 178:            } Line 179:
>   string responseContent; Line 180:            using (var response =
>   request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
>
> Source File: c:\Users\james.billings\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\PhoneMonitor\PhoneMonitor\GoodData\DataRetriever.cs
>   Line: 178
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [IOException: Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.]
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean
>   aborting) +604
>
> [WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.]
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean
>   aborting) +6443608
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState
>   closeState) +37    System.Net.ConnectStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>   +44

Any clues? Specifically I'm trying to use the GoodData API call xtab2/executor3 - see http://docs.gooddata.apiary.io/

If I remove the "`set ContentLength`" I get a 400 Bad Request. If I set to 0 like earlier GET requests (which work fine) I get an error that I tried to write more than the length of the buffer, which makes sense.

Bit stumped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having looked over the docs - [System.IO.StreamWriter.Write()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.write%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - There does not appear to be a method for writing bytes.

The only method that matches the signature is - `StreamWriter.Write(Object)`.  This however calls `ToString()` on the object and writes the output; Which is not what you want.

As you are setting an output buffer; the stream is waiting for this buffer to be filled.  However, the `Object.ToString()` will likely not fill this buffer and hence the error.

Use `BinaryWriter`, `BufferedStream` or another that supports `byte[]` writing.

Answer (score 45):

Do not set `request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;` before writing the request stream. The `request.ContentLength` is set automatically.

Answer (score 6):

For me it was going wrong with a special character (é) in a Json request. For some reason  I *had* to set the ContentLength manually.

Thanks to the tip on [this page](http://csharp.tips/tip/article/7-Bug-Fix---Cannot-close-stream-until-all-bytes-are-written) I changed my code to the following and for me it works now.

Old version:

```
string content = "{ test: \"olé\" }";

_Request.ContentLength  = content.Length;

using ( var writer = new StreamWriter(_Request.GetRequestStream()) ) 
    writer.Write( content );
```

New version:

```
string content = "{ test: \"olé\" }";

byte[] bytes            = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
_Request.ContentLength  = bytes.Length;

using ( var writer = _Request.GetRequestStream() )
    writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```