# Lex chatbot C# client with voice

Tags: c#, .net, naudio, amazon-lex

I have the chatbot client running with text but would now like to change it to voice but I am unsure of how to get the stream from the mic for post. For recording audio I am using NAudio but when sending the memory stream I get an error stating

> System.IO.IOException: Cannot close stream until all bytes are
>   written.

Here is my code:

```
private void recordAudio()
        {
            if (memoryStream == null)
                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
            sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(16000, 1);
            waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider(sourceStream);
            waveWriter = new WaveFileWriter(new IgnoreDisposeStream(memoryStream), waveIn.WaveFormat);
            sourceStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(sourceStream_DataAvailable);
            buff = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveIn.WaveFormat);
            sourceStream.StartRecording();
            mytimer.Enabled = true;

        }
        private void sourceStream_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            buff.AddSamples(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);

            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }
            void mytimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (sourceStream != null)
            {
                sourceStream.StopRecording();
                waveWriter.Flush();



                var amazonLexClient = new AmazonLexClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
                var amazonPostRequest = new Amazon.Lex.Model.PostContentRequest();
                var amazonPostResponse = new Amazon.Lex.Model.PostContentResponse();
                amazonPostRequest.BotAlias = "voiceBot";
                amazonPostRequest.BotName = "voiceBot";
                amazonPostRequest.ContentType = "audio/l16; rate=16000; channels=1";
                amazonPostRequest.UserId = "user";
                amazonPostRequest.InputStream = memoryStream;
                amazonPostRequest.UserId = "test";
                try
                {
                    amazonPostResponse = amazonLexClient.PostContent(amazonPostRequest);
                    Console.WriteLine("Got a response");
                }

                catch (Exception w)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
                    Console.WriteLine(w.Message);
                }
```

Comment: try post existing audio files first then record.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot close stream until all bytes are written (GoodData API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025834/cannot-close-stream-until-all-bytes-are-written-gooddata-api)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the [Position of your MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.position(v=vs.110).aspx) to 0 before you pass it to the post request.

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```