# Encoding speech input for Amazon Lex?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, audio-streaming, amazon-lex

I'm having problem with the encode of speech input for Amazon Lex.

If i assign InputStream as null, it works, i receive the default voice answer from Lex : "How can i help you"

```
            var amazonLexClient = new AmazonLexClient("APPID", "APPSECRET", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            var amazonPostRequest = new Amazon.Lex.Model.PostContentRequest();
            var amazonPostResponse = new Amazon.Lex.Model.PostContentResponse();
            amazonPostRequest.BotAlias = "BookTrip";
            amazonPostRequest.BotName = "BookTrip";
            amazonPostRequest.ContentType = "audio/l16; rate=16000; channels=1";
            amazonPostRequest.UserId = "user";
            amazonPostRequest.InputStream = null;

            amazonPostResponse = await amazonLexClient.PostContentAsync(amazonPostRequest);
```

If i try to send a recorded voice "How are you" using the encode (required by Lex : 16KHz, 8bits, 1 channel) below

```
            var amazonLexClient = new AmazonLexClient("APPID", "APPSECRET", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            var amazonPostRequest = new Amazon.Lex.Model.PostContentRequest();
            var amazonPostResponse = new Amazon.Lex.Model.PostContentResponse();
            amazonPostRequest.BotAlias = "BookTrip";
            amazonPostRequest.BotName = "BookTrip";
            amazonPostRequest.ContentType = "audio/l16; rate=16000; channels=1";
            amazonPostRequest.UserId = "user";
            amazonPostRequest.InputStream = new MemoryStream();

            WaveFormat target = new WaveFormat(16000, 8, 1);
            WaveStream streamIn = new WaveFileReader("F:\\Whatever.wav");
            WaveFormatConversionStream str = new WaveFormatConversionStream(target, streamIn);
            WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(amazonPostRequest.InputStream, str);

            amazonPostResponse = await amazonLexClient.PostContentAsync(amazonPostRequest);
```

Then it doesn't work, after about 20~25s Lex server will return null.

```
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonUnmarshallingException: 'Error unmarshalling response back from AWS.'
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to encode a wav file to make it work with Amazon Lex?
Btw im using Visual Studio 2017, C# with NAudio library.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You should not post code as images, rather as text

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lex chatbot C# client with voice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026213/lex-chatbot-c-sharp-client-with-voice)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Lex expects the audio to be in PCM or Opus format  (read this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostContent.html#API_runtime_PostContent_RequestSyntax) for more details). You can refer this [AI blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ai/capturing-voice-input-in-a-browser/) from Amazon to get more information on how to PCM encode your wav audio.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some kind of problem inside the AWSSDk for c# - what's happened is that the Lex service has returned a plain-text error message, and the SDK is trying to parse it as JSON. Sometimes you can dig into the exception details and find that raw response, or just use Fiddler.